# Python: Confused about what and what should not be defined inside a function

Tags: python, list, function

This is essentially a question about optimising code regards to execution (processing) time from start to finish.

I'm currently learning Python through a project I'm taking on myself, since I'd love to learn more about the language. It's a physics based problem (I'm not in school, this is a hobby for me), and without going into the details it involves calculating the value of a 2D-function (taking two variables as input). The domain of the function is a rectangular grid, defined at around 200x200 points, and at each point I need to evaluate said 2D-function.

Now, to get one (x,y) coordinate I need to perform some deeper calculations (depending on other parameters). I cannot just choose arbitrary of values of (x,y). So it requires some computing - read: processing time - to get (x,y) and then in addition I need to evaluate the actual 2D function on that coordinate.

Here is my question: Should I calculate the (x,y) coordinates by themselves in a separate function in the code, or should I let the 2D-function call another function that calculates the (x,y) grid every time?

Schematically, here are the two alternatives:

(1) xlist and ylist are calculated once and for all

```
def definitions():

    xlist = [ get the values for the x-coordinate ]

    ylist = [ get the values for the y-coordinate ]

    return(xlist,ylist)

def main(xlist,ylist,other parameters):

    # use xlist and ylist in calculations

    return (value of 2D-function at position (x,y))

getcoords = definitions()

for a, b, c in loop:

    result = main(getcoords,a,b,c...)

    write(result onto file)
```

-- OR --

(2) xlist and ylist are calculated anew every time the main function is called

```
def main(a, b, c, ...):

    def definitions():

        xlist = [ get the values for the x-coordinate ]

        ylist = [ get the values for the y-coordinate ]

        return(xlist,ylist)

    getcoords = definitions()

    value = ... # use xlist and ylist in calculations

    return (value)

for a, b, c in loop:

    result = main(a,b,c...)

    write(result onto file)
```

My question stems from the mantra I heard several times that python treats local variables much faster than global variables, and isn't it true that in the first example, the x and y lists are global and needs to be "shipped into" the function every time it is being used? Potentially taking a lot more time to execute than the second example, where the lists are completely local, even though they are re-defined every time the function is called?

Is this question is properly formulated? If there for example are other factors weighing in that I don't know about please let me know, but I just wonder whether its advantageous in general, to redefine lists inside functions time and time again, or rather define them once and keep calling them in the function definition. Maybe there is a better example out there?

Thanks in advance!

PS. Examples of those "deeper calculations" involve using scipy interpolation to evaluate functions not mentioned here, in order to find (x,y).

Comment: Concept of **Separation of Concern**: "Different responsibilities should go into different components, layers, or modules of the application. Each part of the program should only be responsible for a part of the functionality (what we call its concerns) and should know nothing about the rest.".  So separate into different functions which also makes each function more reusable. Also, don't worry at this stage about optimization [Why Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot generally answer that question as it will depend on the complexity of calculating the coordinates in comparison to the number of accesses. I'd assume the first one to be faster, but with no evidence but my gut instinct. However you could use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html) and try both alternatives if that isn't too much trouble code-wise.